# How to save a List<Point> using protobuf.net without using ascii text?

Tags: list, protobuf-net, point

I am attempting to save point data in a list to a protobuf.net created binary file.  While Im not having trouble with this in itself Im also trying to save the data in a format that wont be easily viewable in text editor.  By default when you save a List of Point structs to a text file the x and y for each point are visible as ascii text.

```
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"BufPoints", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    private List<Point> BufPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Points;
        }
        set
        {

            this.Points = value;

        }
    }
```

I have tried creating my own class to save the x and y double data but part of my routine involves a deep clone of the data and the values seem to be lost when preforming this clone.

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"EncodedPoints", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    private List<Utils.PointConverter> EncodedPoints
    {
        get
        {
            List<Utils.PointConverter> temp = new List<Utils.PointConverter>();
            if (Points != null)
            {
                foreach (Point p in this.Points)
                {
                    temp.Add(new Utils.PointConverter(p));
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.Points = new List<Point>();
                foreach (Utils.PointConverter pc in value)
                {
                    this.Points.Add(pc.GetPoint());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

PointsConverter class is bellow:

```
    [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name = @"PointConverter")]
class PointConverter
{
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name = @"X", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public double X;

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true, Name = @"Y", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public double Y;

    public PointConverter(System.Windows.Point point)
    {
        this.X = point.X;
        this.Y = point.Y;
    }

    public PointConverter()
    {

    }

    public System.Windows.Point GetPoint()
    {
        return new System.Windows.Point(X, Y);
    }
}
```

Im unsure why the values are lost during deep clone.  Is there a way to save the data another way in a non ascii format or a way to deal with my issue with the deep clone?

Comment: Can you clarify: at what point are you saving data as ascii? Protobuf data **is not text**, and should not be read/edited in an editor. However, serialization is not encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, protobuf isn't at any point ASCII (although string values are stored as UTF-8, which can often look like ASCII for latin characters without accents) - I can't comment on what you're seeing there without context, but serialization also isn't encryption. Using a binary format can make it *awkward* for someone to read/edit the contents, but do not use it as part of a security check.

As for the code: I think you're over complicating things. Actually, for both `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Windows.Point` the code is *tantalizingly* close to figuring out the mapping automatically as part of the "auto-tuple" handling. But not quite! But we can simply educate it by adding a one-line configuration tweak in your app-startup, telling it to serialize `Point` by storing `.X` as field 1, and `.Y` as field 2. This is just:

```
// either or both; whatever you need
model.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Point), false).Add("X", "Y");
model.Add(typeof(System.Drawing.Point), false).Add("X", "Y");
```

or if you are using the default model instance (i.e. the `Serializer.*` methods):

```
// either or both; whatever you need
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Point), false).Add("X", "Y");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Drawing.Point), false).Add("X", "Y");
```

and... that's it! that is all you need. Members of `Point` or `List<Point>` or `Point[]` should now serialize and deserialize correctly.